# PresentModalViewController with FullScreen to be used with Master_Detail View

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want to use splitviewController in iPad. But before that, I have to display a welcome screen. For that I tried using PresentMiodalViewController in viewDidAppear. (In viewDidLoad it is not getting called). But when I changed the modalPresentationStyle to FullScreen from FormSheet it causes another problem. Welcome screen is coming, but whenever I click on the button, Master_Detail_view is also loading. The problem is From masterViewController-ViewDidLoad it is again going to viewDidAppear ie welcomescreen. What can I do this to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewDidAppear is called whenever the view becomes visible, so in this case it is called when it first displays, AND when you dismiss the welcome screen hence your infinite loop.

I'd create a simply boolean variable in your class that flags whether or not you've displayed it. Then in your viewDidAppear, just check it

```
-(void) viewDidAppear {
    if (!welcomeScreenDisplayed) {
        ... display welcome screen here ...
        welcomeScreenDisplayed = YES;
    }
}
```

Then you'll never get your infinite loop again.

Comment: Thank you very much PaReeOhNos